# SAPUI5 Refresh the service

Tags: sapui5

How to refresh the Odata service in SAPUI5 to get latest data from the service ?

```
var productlist = sap.ui.getCore().byId("productList").getModel().refresh();
```

Comment: var productlist = sap.ui.getCore().byId("productList").getModel().refresh(true);

Comment: Is this above code will work? I have tried above code . But it is not refreshing I think. Because once it is approved it is navigating to the main page and the count of remaining items will be reduced .But it is not getting reduced.

Comment: Share the code.. What are you doing on approval?

Comment: This question is lacking in details and encourages anti-patterns. Voting to close ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the model and refresh the omodel...

Ex: var oModel = sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("your url"); 
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

while refreshing the model....

**sap.ui.getCore().getModel().refresh(true);**

Comment: `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` is deprecated and uses sync XHRs heavily. Combined with `.refresh(true)`, which forces**all** bindings to unnecessarily refresh, it's a desaster in terms of UX. This approach should not be recommended!

Answer (score 0):

you can either invalidate the model which will force to refresh it. You can also, if setting the model in a function, just call that function again.

Answer (score -1):

to refresh data from service you need to refresh only **Model** , and if you want to reflect changes in controls you tah model shuld be **JSON Model** as it is two way

Answer (score -1):

```
var productlist = sap.ui.getCore().byId("productList");
var binding = productlist.getBinding("items");

if(binding){
    binding.refresh(true);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?